# Can can someone please elaborate on this multiple choice question

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Line 11 ("Flexing of structures due to normal atmospheric heating and cooling put much more stress on the waterproof seals") should be rewritten as:

The Correct answer is highlighted in Green.

Could someone please explain why the green highlighted answer is the best choice?

Does it have something to do with subject-verb agreement?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

The bulk of the difference between the first and second sentence feels to me like the second sentence is the right answer.  However, the verb 'put' instead of 'puts' causes it to be wrong.

As Gary Botnovcan said, the top of the screencap explains that.

To keep the verb 'put', the second option would have to change substantially.

```
Normal heating and cooling changes put much more stress on the waterproof seals,
due to the flexing this causes.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ED. It helped me notice the agreement in sentence 1 and the error in sentence 2. I was wondering if you could confirm that sentence 3, 4 and 5 also lack the same grammatical error (subject-verb agreement) as sentence 2?

Comment: I'd not paid as much attention to the other sentences, as they have more issues.  But checking again for you, sentence 1 is the only one that has subject-verb agreement.

Comment: Is comma splice an issue on sentence 5? I'm trying improve my performance when checking for errors.